# Why are my ExpectedConditions commands being ignored? Selenium WebDriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am using Cucumber with Selenium WebDriver to test an application, and I have just noticed that my tests are passing on a particular area, no matter what I put into the parameters of the "ExpectedConditions.textToBe" method.

This part of the tests simple checks that the correct text appears in a table of user roles after the test has added a user:

```
    public void admin_can_see_the_new_role_in_the_list() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    //throw new PendingException();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    ExpectedConditions.textToBe(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"role-nbbbamze\"]"), "account manasdfsdfger");
    ExpectedConditions.textToBe(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/dizz/dib[2]/divz/div[2]zzz/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]"), "Accmasfsdnager");
    ExpectedConditions.textToBe(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/dbiv/div[2]/div/dziv[2]/tzable/tzzzbody/tr[11]/td[3]"), "Can acvfcess the normal dashboard");
}
```

As you can see, I have added random characters to the parameters and the test runs and still passes. It should fail, either because the xpath I have defined doesn't exist - or the text I am asserting does not match anything within that xpath.

I am obviously using the ExpectedConditions wrong, but I can't figure out where or how.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use it in combination with a wait object like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBe(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/dbiv/div[2]/div/dziv[2]/tzable/tzzzbody/tr[11]/td[3]"), "Can acvfcess the normal dashboard"));
```

Comment: Magic! Thank you so much, this has answered my question perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to consider a couple of things :

- Seems you are trying to induce `WebDriverWait`, so you can remove the `Thread.sleep(3000);`
- **`ExpectedConditions`** must be bonded with an instance of **`WebDriverWait`** e.g. **`wait`** along with **`until`** clause as follows:

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBe(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/dbiv/div[2]/div/dziv[2]/tzable/tzzzbody/tr[11]/td[3]"), "Can acvfcess the normal dashboard"));
  ```
- Now, the most important point is, **`textToBe`** clause returns **`boolean`**. So we have check for the returned **`Boolean Status`** as well as follows:

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
  Boolean bool = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBe(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/dbiv/div[2]/div/dziv[2]/tzable/tzzzbody/tr[11]/td[3]"), "Can acvfcess the normal dashboard"));
  ```

Comment: Great point about the Bool, I didn't even think about that. Thank you so much!